# how to recognize USB and mounted state in Android Box

Tags: android

i am developing an android app, and this app need an information about ExternalStoarage State(this mean, USB, Not a SdCard).
so i thought this code could get a USB Mounted State

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState()
```

But it always return about SdCard. I don't know how to access to USB Storage in Android Device. but almost Android device is a Phone so i cannot find about my case

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code block from the [official Android guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host):

```
val manager = getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager
..
val deviceList: HashMap<String, UsbDevice> = manager.deviceList
deviceList.values.forEach { device ->
    //your code
}
```

```
private lateinit var bytes: ByteArray
private val TIMEOUT = 0
private val forceClaim = true

...

device?.getInterface(0)?.also { intf ->
    intf.getEndpoint(0)?.also { endpoint ->
        usbManager.openDevice(device)?.apply {
            claimInterface(intf, forceClaim)
            bulkTransfer(endpoint, bytes, bytes.size, TIMEOUT) //do in another thread
        }
    }
}
```

It will help you to find your USB connected device and communicate with it. Please check the link above for more information.